# Microsoft Graph API: PUT Request files content into binary stream, upload into SharePoint document folder

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, codeigniter-3, sharepoint-api, codeigniter-4

**Problem** I am trying to create a new docx file with some text inside but unable to pass data as there is no example how to upload an actual files in [MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request-to-upload-a-new-file)
don't know what variables to attachment in body for content and binary stream. if i comment the `attachBody()` parameter it will work by only creating a text file in the root of document folder.

```
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$content = [
    'Content-Type: text/plain
        The contents of the file goes here.'
    ];
$data = $graph->createRequest('PUT', '/sites/09e0add7-675f-4694-a1d9-999be420a807/drives/b!163gCV9nlEah2Zmb5CCoBwohbFPtU9lDr3_IcXUI8qiDyOuVQMhDSohSZRBTS6YL/root:/test.docx:/content')
                ->attachBody($content)
                ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
                ->execute();
```

**Problem Updated**
convert text/document/image/ data into binary stream then do the request

**Problem Updated** encoded file is uploaded into the drive but opening will give you error [image]

**printing query before excution below**
[image]

**Code**

```
$text_data=file_get_contents('C:\Users\Lab1-WS-5\Downloads/demo.docx');
    $encoded_text_data=base64_encode($text_data);
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $graph = new Graph();
    $graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    // $content = 'The contents of the file goes here.';
    // $encoded = base64_encode($content);
    $data = $graph->createRequest('PUT', '/sites/09e0add7-675f-4694-a1d9-999be420a807/drives/b!163gCV9nlEah2Zmb5CCoBwohbFPtU9lDr3_IcXUI8qiDyOuVQMhDSohSZRBTS6YL/root:/charlie.docx:/content')
                ->addHeaders(array('Content-Type' => 'text/plain'))
                ->attachBody($encoded_text_data)
                ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
                ->execute();
```

**current issue** Document that is created with graph api is not opening asking for permissions while manual uploaded files are not.

Comment: You can give a try using `$image_data=file_get_contents('test.jpg'); $encoded_image=base64_encode($image_data);` For text files you can use the data directly by setting the Content-Type header to text/plain

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity check my api query it create the document but cannot be open while if u manualy upload docx files it open without any error

Comment: the created file is in base64 and cannot be open also if u download it has base64 code

Answer (score 1):

**PS** Don't need to use encoding base 64 because Microsoft online word will not be able read it

**Working Code**

```
$text_data=file_get_contents('C:\Users\Lab1-WS-5\Downloads/wordfile.docx');
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$data = $graph->createRequest('PUT', '/sites/09e0add7-675f-4694-a1d9-999be420a807/drives/b!163gCV9nlEah2Zmb5CCoBwohbFPtU9lDr3_IcXUI8qiDyOuVQMhDSohSZRBTS6YL/root:/wordfile1.docx:/content')
                ->addHeaders(array('Content-Type' => 'text/plain'))
                ->attachBody($text_data)
                ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
                ->execute();
```

**PS**
This code will work with anyfile i have tested excel and word